# Как определять просматриваемые посты пользователем на данный момент и отправлять их по WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть сайт со списком постов -- обычные `div`ы. Допустим, в базе сайта 1000 постов, на странице показывается 10, можно подгрузить еще 10, потом еще.. и так до последнего поста.

Хочу сделать систему лайков, и чтобы при лайке отправлялось событие всем пользователям, просматриваемым этот пост на данный момент.

(но я же не могу отправлять инфу обо всех постах (1000) на всех посетителей онлайн (200-500). за 1 лайк 200-500 пакетов отправится. Если каждый пользователь лайкнет минимум 5 раз? 200 * 1000 * 5 = 1000000 пакетов за несколько секунд? для двухсот посетителей? Не дело(

Событие о лайке напрямую взаимодействует с сокет-сервером, и получается так, что когда пользователь лайкает какой-то пост, сокет сервер готов уже отправлять событие, но я не понимаю как определить, кому надо отправлять это событие -- как определить просматриваемых пользователей того поста, который только что лайкнули, чтобы обновить у них счетчик???

***В общем, нужны мысли.***

Comment: Немного не помимаю, что значит "просматривающие" - это те, кто непосредственно находится на уровне данного поста, или те, кто заходил на него, или может те, кто отметил его как то?

Comment: При лайке, в первую очередь, нужно обновить данные в базе, тогда пользователи при обновлении страницы увидят изменения. То, что Вы пытаетесь сделать (отправлять или даже уведомлять пользователя обо всех изменениях в постах) на мой взгляд излишне. Можно просто уведомить пользователя, просматривающего конкретный пост, о том, что данный пост был изменен (как это реализовано, допустим, в Stackoverflow). Система просто уведом Вас о том, что произошли изменения, но ничего не обновляет (для этого Вам нужно перезагрузить страничку, чтобы сделать запрос в бд).

Comment: @notaProgrammer вы же не программист, как вы можете советовать что-то?

Comment: @notaProgrammer и вы задали мне свой вопрос, идентичный тому, который я задал вам

Comment: А если бы у меня был ник "JavaScript co-founder" прислушались бы к каждому слову?

Comment: @notaProgrammer на сообщение выше взгляните, будьте добры

Comment: Когда я Вам задавал вопрос?

Comment: @notaProgrammer 

Из вашего поста::

>> Можно просто уведомить пользователя, просматривающего конкретный пост, о том, что данный пост был изменен

Это и есть мой вопрос. Но как уведомить вы не сказали.

Comment: Почитайте что такое `broadcast`, `emit` и разницу между ними. Как ними пользоватся. (я говорю о реализации на socket.io)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич так вопрос в том, как определить те посты, которые пользователи смотрят на данный момент

Comment: Слушаете событие scroll, определяете текущий пост, на который смотрит пользователь. Отправляете эту инфу на сервер. На сервере сохраняете эту информацию в бд. При лайке, смотрите кто смотрит данный пост, отправляете им информацию. Не забудьте очищать данные при уходе пользователя с сайта!